# How can I make an infinite image loop?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sass, flexbox

There are a lot of similar threads, but I couldn't manage to find an answer to my question.

So, I'm making a model for a website, and I would like to implement an infinite rotating gallery, of course, with a limited number of images. To be more clear, the images should slowly move to the left and cycle seamlessly in an infinite loop through the image array.

For now, here's my code:

> src/component/RotatingGallery/index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../css/RotatingGallery/index.scss';

import mariage1 from '../../assets/mariage1.jpg';
import mariage2 from '../../assets/mariage2.webp';
import mariage3 from '../../assets/mariage3.jpg';
import mariage4 from '../../assets/mariage4.jpg';
import mariage5 from '../../assets/mariage5.png';
import mariage6 from '../../assets/mariage6.jpg';

const images = [mariage1, mariage2, mariage3, mariage4, mariage5, mariage6];

const RotatingGallery = () => {
  return (
    <section className="Gallery">
      <h1>Mes récents projets</h1>
      <div className="GalleryContent">
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="image">
            <img src={image} alt={`Image ${index + 1}`} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default RotatingGallery;

export default RotatingGallery;
```

> src/css/RotatingGallery/index.scss

```
.Gallery {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 60vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  font-family: 'Bodoni Moda', serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.GalleryContent {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  animation: scrollImages 60s linear infinite;
}

.image {
  width: calc(100% / 6); 
  height: 600px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@keyframes scrollImages {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

It does, in fact, cycle, and it's infinite too, but it's not seamless at all. When it reaches the last image, it waits for it to exit the screen before looping again, creating a huge gap.

This would be the biggest issue I'd like to fix. But there's also the fact that the gap between images is really inconsistent. I'd like to have a 30px gap between each image, no more, no less.

I had an idea on how to implement it, maybe, I could make it so when the image reaches a certain point, it teleports to the start while fading in opacity. So, on a big screen, it doesn't just pop out of nowhere or just disappear. But I'm not sure how to implement it.

Another solution would be to have some kind of infinite array where the image that appears is selected with an index that loops around the array, thus ensuring there is always a picture to show. But that means that I also have to delete images at some point to avoid overflowing the memory. Again, I'm not sure how I could do it.

Thank you for your help! I'm waiting for your wise answers :)

Comment: you want to add a slider with infinite scroll right?

Comment: no I want it to scroll on it's own, just an animation showcasing multiple images. I'm not sure if that's what you call a slider

Comment: you want to scroll them horizontally or vertically

Comment: I want them horizontally

Comment: no i  have't downvoted uh just asked to underdtand clearly...wait ill give you the code

Comment: i have posted the answer try it and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**First install slick-slider library by using the command:**

> npm i react-slick

> npm i slick-carousel

**now use this code**

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

import mariage1 from '../../assets/mariage1.jpg';
import mariage2 from '../../assets/mariage2.webp';
import mariage3 from '../../assets/mariage3.jpg';
import mariage4 from '../../assets/mariage4.jpg';
import mariage5 from '../../assets/mariage5.png';
import mariage6 from '../../assets/mariage6.jpg';



export default function RotatingGallery() {
  var settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 200,
    autoplay:true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  };
  const images = [mariage1, mariage2, mariage3, mariage4, mariage5, mariage6];
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Slider {...settings}>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="image">
            <img src={image} alt={`Image ${index + 1}`} />
          </div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**just do the necessary changes if required.**

Comment: so, I've tried your code, it seemed like it was missing two ")" and a "}" but I fixed it. The issue is that nothing displays when loading the page, everything works fine except the carousel, that leaves a huge blank gap. No errors in the console, just had to "npm install slick-carousel". Any idea?

Comment: you have to download slick-carousel as it is depended on that library..is it working?

Comment: As I told you, I downloaded it but it doesn't work

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-forked-dp24ml?file=/index.js have a look here.. maybe you have something wrong with the links of the images that's why your are getting nothing

Comment: looking at what you sent me, I'm not sure you got what I meant.
Here's a record I took of how it should look, including the issues I have (refer to the main post) as you can see it moves itself, showcasing multiple images but it's broken when it reaches the last image and the gaps are incoherent
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qerpWhTWqdg

Comment: you can do it with slick slider just go to the website and update the code accordingly i have given you the boiler plate according to the question asked now whole code cant be given